# Show top n-results in dc.js chart

Tags: javascript, charts, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dataset with many (thousands) of 'categories'. I want to show a row chart with the top 15 categories, but can't figure out how. Without any default 'filters', the row chart shows every single category on the chart, which looks bad. I only want to show the top 15 categories, but based on the current crossfilter filters. How can I do that using dc.js & crossfilter?

Currently, my dimension function looks like:

```
const myCategoriesDimension = crossFilterData.dimension(
        (d) => {
          return d.category;
        } );
```

And my group function looks like:

```
const myGroup = myCategoriesDimension.group();
```

My row chart looks like:

```
 categoriesChart
        .width(1200)
        .height(1200)
        .dimension(myCategoriesDimension)
        .group(myGroup)
        .elasticX(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `.cap()`

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.capMixin+cap

It's not available for all charts but it is available for the row chart.

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what I needed. I added .rowsCap(15) and .othersGrouper(False) to my chart initialization and it worked perfectly.

Comment: super tip. Thanks. Just a short remark. It should be `.othersGrouper(false) `, though.